# Partial derivative of one component of coordinate system in terms of another

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading through Spivak's *Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, vol. 1*. On page 35 I encountered the following:

Let $(x, U)$ be some coordinate system with $x(p) = (x^1(p), \ldots, x^n(p))$ and $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Define
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p) = D_i(f \circ x^{-1})(x(p))
$$

Notice that
$$
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j}(p) = \delta_j^i = \begin{cases}
1 & \mathrm{if}\;i=j \\
0 & \mathrm{if}\; i\neq j
\end{cases}
$$

I have been trying to prove this assertion but I can't seem to get anywhere. Any help would be amazing!

---

**EDIT:**

I may have figured it out:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j}(p) &= D_i(x^j \circ x^{-1})(x(p))
\\& = D_i(x \circ x^{-1})^j(x(p))
\\& = D_i(I^j)(x(p)) = \begin{cases}
1 & \mathrm{if}\; i=j\\
0 & \mathrm{if}\; i\neq j
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

Where $I$ is the identity map.

Comment: Yes your edit is correct, and more specifically it's the identity map on $x(U)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my edit and peek-a-boo's confirmation, here is the proof:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j}(p) &= D_i(x^j \circ x^{-1})(x(p))
\\& = D_i(x \circ x^{-1})^j(x(p))
\\& = D_i(I^j)(x(p)) = \begin{cases}
1 & \mathrm{if}\; i=j\\
0 & \mathrm{if}\; i\neq j
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
Where $I$ is the identity map on $x(U)$.